# What is linker for bluez shell.h declarations

Tags: c, gcc, linker, bluez

I am at the final point of implementing a ble app based on bluez 5.62
However gcc cannot compile because of several "undefined reference" e.g. `bt_shell_printf'". They are *all* declared in shell.h: shell.h is a member of the bluez stack.
I have linked pkg-config for dbus-1, dbus-glib-1, bluez and glib-2.0 but there must be something else that I'm not seeing. Every other declaration is recognised.
What is the gcc linker that I need?
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04), bluez-5.62, linked in netbeans as 'pkg-config --libs dbus-1', 'pkg-config --libs dbus-glib-1', 'pkg-config --libs bluez', 'pkg-config --libs glib-2.0'.

Comment: `However gcc cannot compile because of several` Please show the exact linker command that you use including all options, post gcc version and bluez version and Linux distribution that you use, please post verbatim linker messages that you get. `I have linked...` _How_? Please post the exact command. Are you aware that the order of command line arguments for the linker matters?

Comment: Version data added to question.<br> Message example: gcc -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/bluerplus build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/580d5b24/main.o `pkg-config --libs dbus-1` `pkg-config --libs dbus-glib-1` `pkg-config --libs bluez` /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluetooth.a `pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` -ldbus-1  
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
/usr/bin/ld: build/Debug/GNU-Linux/_ext/580d5b24/main.o: in function `activate_adv_monitor':
/home/user/NetBeansProjects/BluerPlus/main.c:90: undefined reference to `bt_shell_printf'

Comment: Can you post the output of `pkg-config --libs bluez`?

Comment: prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include
 
Name: BlueZ
Description: Bluetooth protocol stack for Linux
Version: 5.62
Libs: -L${libdir} -lbluetooth
Cflags: -I${includedir}

Comment: You can only use the API's defined in `/usr/include/bluetooth/` if you want to link against `-lbluetooth`. `bt_shell_printf` belongs to internal bluez implementation. Check and use the DBUS API's